# How to load and parse the content of a text file into diferent variables [c++]

Tags: c++

i'm learning the basics of c++.
also at the same time i try to aplly what i've learned into a project.
i'm trying to make a GUI program for a command-line program.
the purpose of that program is to interact with PS2 Hard Drives, and i want to automate almost every feature it has.
the first thing i'm trying to do is parse a text file dumped by the program:
the text file contains a list of elements.
every element will contain this :

`"media"      "size"                         "Region Code"        "name of the game"`

Also, at the end of the file the total,used and free space of the HDD is written:

`total 305152MB, used 199296MB, available 105856MB`

I need to store into arrays (or vectors) the data of every game and the HDD space

Here's an example of what the text file looks like
https://mega.nz/file/o85SmLBZ#qf8FCXByI5-icz9LlSNFGiL7JXFArpwxODDLNrQ1LPc

Whatever I write to handle this will be executed several times (after erasing or installing games)

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you're a new contributor, so I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please edit your question to include your attempts so far, and what precise problem you encounter.

Comment: Did you read a [good C++ programming book](https://stroustrup.com/programming.html). Did you read the documentation of your C++ compiler (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...)? Did you look into [this C++ reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) ? StackOverflow is not a *do-my-homework* website. For your next question, please provide some [mre]

Comment: **Also, your question is [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) specific**. The C++11 standard [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) does not know about HDD space. For Linux, start by reading about [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read and write to and from files, I suppose your best bet is the fstream library, which well... is used specifically to do that.

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_files.asp) is a simple tutorial for the most fundamental ways to use the library.

Using this, you will read the file. There are examples for reading values one-by-one, but since the last line is specific, you might want to look into `getline` which shows up in that tutorial too.

Parsing it is the logic of your program, so I guess the first thing you want to do is put the values you read into arrays of some sort.